# Attributes in Java Interface

Tags: java, interface

I have read some articles and oracle documentation, but there are not enough examples of when, how are attributes in Java interface used. From some resources I understood that interface attributes can have only static final attribute types and you have to initialize them. On the other side, some articles said that there is a way to create variables inside interface which does not make sense to me. [Link to article](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/interfaces.html#interface-variables)
Can anybody clarify how actually interface attributes in Java works? And also say I have Drawable interface and it has static field width, can I access that field by Drawing.width?

Comment: You could try it out

Comment: And link the articel that  states " is a way to create variables inside interface"

Comment: You can have members in an interface but they will be static and final rather than members of any instances that implement the interface.

Comment: Properties on interfaces should be avoided as it can reveal implementation of your code, which a interface should hide.

Comment: Usually I read article and documentation to know exactly how it should behave, if I experiment I might miss some points and my knowledge would be weak.

Comment: The articel is misleading. It uses the term "variables" where constants wouldbe more appropriate..

Answer (score 1):

I tried it out for you:

The field defined in a interface are static final, altough it is not neccessary to use the "static final" keywords: This is analogous to the fact that all methods are public altough it is not necessary to use the public keyword.

Sometimes it makes sense to use that for constants, to avoid duplicate
definitions.
Imagine an interface that is used in storing versioned objects:
And the maximum version is limited to 255, due the limitation of an underlying protocol.

```
public interface IVersion {

    int MAX_VERSION = 255;
    int getVersion();
    /** 
         The implementing class should throw a
         IllegalArgumentException when version exceed MAX_VERSION
     */
    void setVersion(int version);
}
```